# Counting values in a field (value_count)

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I’m using Grafana to display metrics from Elasticsearch.

I want to count the number of values in a field and shows them in a graph

Like I do in Elasticsearch

for example:

```
POST /sales/_search?size=0
{
    “aggs” : {
        “types_count” : { 
            “value_count” : { “field” : “type” } 
        }
    }
}
```

I try to convert it like that with no success

```
aggs(types_count(value_count(demand=type)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried count(metricname{fieldName="fieldValue"})? This will always show a 1. Or did you mean to directly specify its value?

Comment: Tnx for your replay I do not want to show a 1
 I want to count the number of values.
In my example, I have one field that has 15 keys every one of them as a different value.
example{ key1:value}
example{ key2:value}
I need to show/count the number to keys
tnx